# eventlistener runs without clicking

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

```
document.getElementById("hit").addEventListener("click",console.log('test'))
```

I have that line of code, hit is an id of a button : `<button id = "hit" value="Hit">Hit</button>` Refreshing the page outputs "test" in the console and i dont know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you pass parameters to a function it is immediately called. You need to pass a function that will wait for the event and then call `console.log` with the specified parameters.

```
document.getElementById("hit").addEventListener("click",() => console.log('test'))
```

Answer (score 3):

`addEventListener("click",console.log('test'))` will immediately run `console.log('test')` and pass the return value of `console.log`. The return value will be undefined, so **your code is equivalent to this**:

```
document.getElementById("hit").addEventListener("click", undefined);
console.log('test');
```

**OR**

```
const consoleReturnValue = console.log('test'); // will be undefined
document.getElementById("hit").addEventListener("click", consoleReturnValue );
```

I assume that what you are you trying to achieve is

`addEventListener("click", () => console.log('this'));`

Or, if you can't use ES6:

`addEventListener("click", console.log.bind(window, 'this'));`

In this case you actually pass a `function` as the second argument instead of the `undefined` primitve.

---

**Fun fact**, passing `undefined` as an argument is the same as not passing it, so your current `addEventLinster` call is the same as as:

```
document.getElementById("hit").addEventListener("click");
console.log('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

#### In the event listener, using a function that takes parameters will automatically run the function, try this instead.

`document.getElementById("hit").addEventListener("click", function (){
    console.log('test');
});`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) so that you will see that good answers should explain what the problem was and how your suggestion solves the problem. Simply providing code is not a good answer and will likely get your answers down voted even if the code is correct.